# Slow JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got an HTML form where the maximum field value is set to 1 character. As a result, the JavaScript needs to be super-fast. But upon testing, it appears I am too fast for the script, so it misses characters unless I type slowly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function formfocus() {
      document.getElementById('element').focus();
   }
   window.onload = formfocus;

function moveOnMax(field,nextFieldID){
  if(field.value.length >= field.maxLength){
    document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
  }
}
</script>

<input class="text" type="text" name="1" id="element" maxlength="1" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'2')"><input class="text" id="2" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'3')" type="text" name="2" maxlength="1">
```

Anyone know a way to speed this up, or am I stuck with having to instruct visitors to type slowly?

Comment: That's not a problem of speed, but depends on the events you're listening too. Please include the code that registers the `moveOnMax` event handler.

Comment: What event are you using to call the javascript and how are you attaching it?

Comment: You are not showing all your code, are you? Where do you attach the keypress event.

Comment: Added the input HTML. For what it's worth, all fields will be 1 character maximum, so if there's a generally easier way to do that then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned maxlength of all fields are 1 character, then why to check length of the values of each field just in **onkeyup** event handler of every field make the focus to next field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function formfocus() {
      document.getElementById('element').focus();
   }
   window.onload = formfocus;

function moveOnMax(nextFieldID){
    document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
}
</script>

<input class="text" type="text" name="1" id="element" maxlength="1" onkeyup="moveOnMax('2')">
<input class="text" id="2" onkeyup="moveOnMax('3')" type="text" name="2" maxlength="1">
<input class="text" id="3" onkeyup="moveOnMax('4')" type="text" name="2" maxlength="1">
```

Comment: Your code is certainly smaller, but unfortunately I can still type faster than the JavaScript can tell my cursor to move.

Comment: In place of **onkeyup** event handler, use **onkeypress** event handler. it works...